# Kafka connect-distributed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, control-center

When I am trying to start connect-distributed.
It is throwing me a WARN message. My main goal is to implement Control center Interceptors for the Splunk Sink.
And it is giving me this:

> WARN The configuration 'consumer.interceptor.classes' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:231).

I am trying to overcome this WARN messages. Now my main doubt is whether the given properties file is loaded or not?

The connect-distributed property file is below:

```
bootstrap.servers="Removed for posting"
group.id=splunk-connect-testinterceptorconnect
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets-splunk-testinterceptorconnect
offset.storage.replication.factor=3
offset.storage.partitions=5
config.storage.topic=connect-configs-splunk-testinterceptorconnect
config.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.topic=connect-status-splunk-testinterceptorconnect
status.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.partitions=5
offset.flush.interval.ms=50000
rest.port=8000 


consumer.interceptor.classes=io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor
plugin.path=/usr/share/java,/opt/connect/
```

All other configs also gave the same WARN as below
Log:

> [2018-03-05 18:09:33,339] WARN The configuration 'consumer.interceptor.classes' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:231)

Comment: "was supplied but isn't a known config." Is just noise.... Is there an actual error?

Comment: No, But thank you for the Answer cricket. I thought it was an error.